# How to send the client id and secret id of OAuth2 using AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, curl, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

I have the Rest API for OAuth2 developed using spring boot with resource server and authorization server. I could successfully fetch the token using cURL, POSTMAN Rest client and could request the granted service using the token provided by OAuth. Now, i need to know how to pass the OAuth2 client_id, secret_id using angularjs and also i would like to know what's the usage of -vu in the following curl request,

```
    curl -X POST -vu clientapp:123456 http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=spring&username=roy&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp".

  Could anyone please help me to know about this and provide me the samples to work on with angularjs ?
```

TIA..,

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example from jhipster: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-oauth2/blob/master/src/main/webapp/scripts/components/auth/provider/auth.oauth2.service.js

Note: I'd probably simply use a blank client secret (both in angularjs AND spring) since the secret isn't really secret in js anyway. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32062458/1098564 and below:

```js
return {
   login: function(credentials) {
      var data = "username=" + credentials.username + "&password=" + credentials.password + "&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&";
      return $http.post('oauth/token', data, {
         headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Basic " + Base64.encode("myapp" + ':' + "")
         }
      }).success(function (response) {
         var expiredAt = new Date();
         expiredAt.setSeconds(expiredAt.getSeconds() + response.expires_in);
         response.expires_at = expiredAt.getTime();
         localStorageService.set('token', response);
         return response;
      });
   },
```

As for curl, the -v option is for "verbose" and the -u option is to pass the user credentials (options explained here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.